# Ang2/Observables - Reading a Cookie value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-observables

Angular 2/Observables - Reading the login credentials set in cookie from Backend. Any plnkr example or anyone accomplished this ?

Answer (score 0):

To set a cookie from the backend. send a set-cookie response header after successful authentication.

additionally, you can use [javascripts cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) to set cookie manually.

and use an [AuthGuard](https://gist.github.com/Sibiraj-S/abd71626fbcc26fc220bd3e36a3c522d) to check authentication

Answer (score 0):

try this to read the cookie value...

```
private findCookie(name: string): string | null {
    let results = document.cookie
        .split('; ')
        .filter((s: string) => { return s.startsWith(name + '=') });
    if (results.length === 1) {
        return results[0].split('=')[1];
    }
    return null;
}
```

...accessing the credentials depends on how they are encoded